# Upper Bound of a Subseries of a Positive Convergent Sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $(a_n) \to 0$ and that $a_n >0, \forall n$. I am trying to show that:
$$
\exists (a_{n_k}): \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_{n_k}<1
$$
Thought: I can show that $(a_n)$ has a strictly decreasing subsequence. Because $(a_n) \to 0$, this subsequence can be constructed to have an upper bound as small as needed. I think this has to do with this question. Other than that, I am not sure how to tackle the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**

Since $a_n\to 0$, there exists $n_1<n_2<\dotsb$ such that
$$
0<a_{n_k}< \frac{1}{4^k}.
$$ 
Now sum over $k$ and use the formula for a geometric series.

Comment: Thank you! Just a related question though: here you use $\frac{1}{4^k}$, but we can underestimate the sum by using an even smaller number, correct? Similarly, if we use $\frac{1}{2^k}$, then we can obtain a tighter bound (=1). Also, is there a general result behind this particular question?